# Difference in matrix multiplication tensorflow vs numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tensorflow

I have a case where matrix multiplication of two matrices with certain dimensions work in numpy, but doesn't work in tensorflow.

```
x = np.ndarray(shape=(10,20,30), dtype = float)
y = np.ndarray(shape=(30,40), dtype = float)
z = np.matmul(x,y)
print("np shapes: %s x %s = %s" % (np.shape(x), np.shape(y), np.shape(z)))
```

This works as expected and prints:

```
np shapes: (10, 20, 30) x (30, 40) = (10, 20, 40)
```

However in tensorflow when I try to multiply placeholder and variable of the same shapes as the numpy arrays above I get an error

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(10,20,30))
y = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([30,40], name='w'))
print("tf shapes: %s x %s" % (x.get_shape(), y.get_shape()))
tf.matmul(x,y)
```

Results in

```
tf shapes: (10, 20, 30) x (30, 40)
InvalidArgumentError: 
Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_12' 
(op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [10,20,30], [30,40].
```

Why does this operation fail?

Comment: what does numpy matmul do here? Broadcast second entry to 10,20,30 and do 10 matmuls of 20,30 by (30,40)? It seems TF matmul is missing broadcasting, might be worth filing a feature request. You can trigger broadcasting by doing `y = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([30,40], name='w')+tf.zeros((10,30,40)))` . Related issue (possibly closed by mistake) -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/216

Comment: matmul here does the same as `np.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', x, y)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why `tf.matmul` does not support this kind of multiplication (may be one of the core developers could provide a meaningful answer).

But if you just want to be able to multiply tensors in this way, take a look at [tf.einsum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) function. It could operate with tensors of arbitrary rank.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dmytro `tf.einsum` can be used to multiply these two arrays.

```
x = np.ndarray(shape=(10,20,30), dtype = float)
y = np.ndarray(shape=(30,40), dtype = float)
```

These two operations produce exactly the same result:

```
np.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', x, y)
np.matmul(x,y)
```

And corresponding tensorflow operation also works

```
tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', tf_x,tf_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

People already told you that you can use [tf.einsum()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum)  to get the result you want.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.random_normal([10, 20, 30])
y = tf.random_normal([30, 40])
z = tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', x, y)
```

The reason why [tf.matmul()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) does not work the way you expected is written in the documentation.

> The inputs must be matrices (or tensors of rank > 2, representing
>   batches of matrices), with matching inner dimensions, possibly after
>   transposition.

In your case you have a matrix `y` and a tensor `x` (rank 3 > 2). In your case inner dimensions do not match. If you want, them to match, you will need to have something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a, b, c = 12, 50, 20
x = tf.random_normal([a, b, c])
y = tf.random_normal([a, c, b])
z = tf.matmul(x, y)
```

But clearly it calculates not the stuff you want.